# error handling in codeigniter: who should call show_error()

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

I have a question about error handling in codeigniter. 
My first question is who should call the show_error method?  The model or the controller or the view? 
I was going to put it in the model for this particular case because the model is where the error is generated, but since most of my business logic is in the controller I decided to do it there.  BUt I'd like to know if there is a "correct" way to do this.

My second question is this.  In the model, i have added two functions- one to return data, and the other to return an error message.  My controller tests for an error condition after calling my model, and attempts to display it.  But its always empty.

My model looks something like this:

```
    public function errormessage()
    {
        return $this->_emess;
    }
    public someotherfunction()
    {
         if ( $switch_obj->connect() )
        {
            $retdata = $switch->showInterfaceAll(); 
            $switch->disconnect();  
            $this->_data = $retdata;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            print 'debug: assigning error message in model:';
            $this->_emess = $switch->errormessage();
            print $this->_emess;
            return false;
        }
          }
```

Then in my controller, i have the following logic:

```
      if ($this->switches_model->someotherfunction($this->uri->segment(7) ) )
      {      
      $data['listofports'] = $this->switches_model->data;
      }
      else {
              print '<BR>in error path<BR>';
      show_error($this->switches_model->errormessage(), 123);
      }
```

From my debug print statements in the model, i know that an error message has been set.  But by the time the controller tries to display it using the show_error() method, i'm getting the following error message:

> No status text available. Please check your status code number or
>   supply your own message text.

To prove that its not because the model has already been destroyed, I tried adding a destructor in my model and printing out a debug line...

```
    public function __destruct()
    {
      print 'in the destructor';
    }
```

The message "in error path" is printed before "in the destructor" so I'm assuming that the model is still alive and well...

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

I found my problem.  You need to pass a legit status code, if you're going to pass one at all. 
I thought you could create custom status numbers, but they must be HTTP codes.  But if someone could comment on question 1 about who should call show_error() that'd be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your first question is no, there is not a "correct" way to do it.

In your question, you said:

> since most of my business logic is in the controller I decided to do it there.

This is up for debate and is probably not a debate that should be had on this site but I have found that generally, the controller is meant to be more of a dispatcher then anything else. So, your controller should be as small as possible. That being said, since the show_error() function is also deciding what view to display, I would call that a dispatching function and would put it in the controller. If you were not using that function but were using log_message() instead to store the error in a log and continue processing, then I would put that in the model because you can continue through the process after using that function. Again, this is personal choice and can be done either place but that is how I usually look at it.